# Eclipse marking previously valid Java syntax as error

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax

I have a new Eclipse installation I am pointing to an existing workspace and project.  In my previous Eclipse installation I had no errors in my project and everything ran fine.  Now, Eclipse is pointing out syntax that was previously valid as now being in error.  For example:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Foo{
```

Eclipse is marking the SuppressWarnings line as a syntax error.  Another example:

```
public HashMap<String, String> data;
```

Eclipse is marking the < and > characters as errors.  I have seen people with a similar issue and it seems like a Project->clean, then build fixed it for them.  This is not working for me.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you checked the build set-up? Both those errors could be caused by using a very old compiler, before generics and before annotations.

Comment: This sounds like either an old compiler (@PatriciaShanahan's comment) or a missing item, maybe a close-brace or a semicolon, earlier in the code.

Comment: I think it may be the compiler issue you mention.  I'm looking at the Eclipse versions, and I think what was given to me today is an older version than what I was previously using.  I'll see if I can get the project running in the latest version and get back to you.

Comment: The two theories can be distinguished. If it is a compiler version issue, **every** error will relate to a feature that was added after JDK 1.0. If it is file corruption or incorrect version, so there are genuine syntax errors, some of them are likely to relate to base features that have always been there.

Comment: Check your project properties and see what the source code level is. If the source code is 1.4 or under you should get this problem.

Comment: Yea, it must have been the old compiler issue. Once I got the latest version of Eclipse up and running there was no problem.